# How to hide the scrollbar while keeping the cursors to go up or down in css

Tags: html, css

All is in the title, I want to hide the scrollbar while keeping the cursors (see the image). Is it possible in css ? All I found on internet was to hide all (scrollbar + cursors, I didn't found something to hide only the bar).

Thank you

Cursors + scrollbar:

[image: Cursors + scrollbar]

Comment: i think this is not possible, but if its possible. it will probably only be for webkit browsers, alternative is creating up and down buttons yourself with `html`+ `javascript`/`jquery`

Comment: this will help you http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just paste the code down below and you can get a scroll area with just scroll buttons.
You can check out a sample here

```
<style>
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 20px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:start {
  background: url('https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/3/3892.svg') no- 
  repeat center center;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:end {
  background: url('https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/3/3907.svg') no- 
  repeat center center;
  
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  display:none;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you ! That's almost what I want. I tried with your code to replace the black square with an image of cursor like my pic on my first post, but nothing happened. Do you have an idea if it's possible to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

```css
.scrollable-content {
  height: 180px;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: blue;
}

.scrollable-content::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 2em;
    height: 2em
}

.scrollable-content::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
    background: no-repeat #e9ecef;
    background-size: 0.75em;
    background-position: center bottom;
}

.scrollable-content::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:decrement {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100' height='100' fill='%235a6268'><polygon points='0,50 100,50 50,0'/></svg>");   
}

.scrollable-content::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:increment {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100' height='100' fill='%235a6268'><polygon points='0,0 100,0 50,50'/></svg>");
}
```

```html
<div class="scrollable-content">
        <p>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        <p>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        <p>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        <p>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        <p>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        <p>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        <p>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        <p>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
  </div>
```

check this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/2zmf1wbj/

Comment: Thank you for your help but your code hide all the scrollbar and the cursors and that's not what I really want.

Comment: Sorry i didn't see your picture at first, check the code was updated!